# parse address with regex to get city name and state name

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex to parse the normal address to get city name and state name:
here are use cases:

```
124 MAIN ST, UNIT 2, STEAMBOAT, CO 76543
124 MAIN ST UNIT 2, STEAMBOAT, CO, 76543
124 MAIN ST, STEAMBOAT, CO, 76543
124 MAIN ST, STEAMBOAT, CO 76543
```

I need to get output as: STEAMBOAT and CO
This is what i tried, but does not work for city name

```
,?([^.]+), ([A-Z]{2}) (\d{5})
```

and suggestion?

Comment: Can the city name ever be 2 (or 3) words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try with this one:

```
^(?:.*,)?\s*(.*?),\s*([A-Z]{2}),?\s*\d{5}$
```

I assume it covers your criteira.
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zd4Rf4/1)

Explanation:

1. `^` : start of a string
2. `(?:.*,)?` :
   a) `(?:.*,)` matches everything until it reaches a final comma.

   b) `?`- means that it is optional
3. `(.*?),` :  it targets the city name which expect a comma after it
4. `\s*([A-Z]{2})` :

   a) `\s*` 0 or more empty space

   b) `([A-Z]{2})` state
5. `,?\s*\d{5}` :

   a) `,?` - comma is optional,

   b) `\s*` zero or more blank space,

   c) `\d{5}` 5digit number
6. `$` : end of string

Code Snippet( [run](https://ideone.com/Tu9UmV) )

```
regex = r"^(?:.*,)?\s*(.*?),\s*([A-Z]{2}),?\s*\d{5}$"

test_str = ("124 MAIN ST, UNIT 2, STEAMBOAT, CO 76543\n"
    "124 MAIN ST UNIT 2, STEAMBOAT, CO, 76543\n"
    "124 MAIN ST, STEAMBOAT, CO, 76543\n"
    "124 MAIN ST, STEAMBOAT, CO 76543\n"
    "STEAMBOAT, GO 12345\n")


matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for match in matches:
    print("City= "+match.group(1)+" State= "+match.group(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `re.findall` here:

```py
inp = "124 MAIN ST, UNIT 2, STEAMBOAT SPRINGS, CO 76543"
matches = re.findall(r'^.*, (.*?), [A-Z]{2} \d{5}$', inp)
print(matches[0])  # STEAMBOAT SPRINGS
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern used:

```regex
^             from the start of the address
    .*        match all content up until
    ,[ ]      a comma and space
    (.*?)     then match and capture the city name (any number of words)
    ,[ ]      comma and space
    [A-Z]{2}  a two letter state abbreviation
    [ ]       space
    \d{5}     ZIP code
$             end of the address
```